# ImportError: cannot import name 'second_file'

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have two files first_file and second_file in the same directory dir.
When I am trying to import second_file in first_file using

> from dir import second_file

I am getting ImportErorr.
I have also tried using

> from . import second_file

in the first_file but still I am getting that error.
I am using Python 3.6
How to import correctly?

Comment: Does `dir` contain an `__init__.py`?

Comment: How are you running this? Command line?

Comment: have you tried `import second_file`? if they are in the same directory it should be fine just to call an import.

Comment: Yes the directory contains __init__.py

Comment: I have run this from pycharm run configuration as well as from the terminal using py filename.py still getting the same error.

Comment: The pycharm is detecting the import but while running the script it is giving me the error.

Comment: Are you sure it is while importing and not later in the script

Answer (score 1):

You are importing wrongly.  To get a file that is in the same dictionary use:

```
import second_file
```

Assuming the following structure:

```
dir -|
      -  __init__.py
      -  first_file.py
      -  second_file.py
```

You will also need an `__init__.py` file ([see why here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for))

The command:

```
from dir import second_file
```

Will import second_file from a package (or sub-folder) with the following structure:

```
main_folder |-
              |-  first_file.py
              |-  dir  |-
                         |-  __init__.py
                         |-  second_file.py
```

`from . import second_file` will have this structure:

```
main_folder |-
              |- __init__.py
              |- second_file.py
              |- dir |-
                       |- first_file.py
```

The section of the Python documentation relating to [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) might be helpful to you as well.

Comment: @SriDivya  Hmmm What is your file structure?  Also what does your `__init__.py` contain?  This is certainly the way to import without more details it is not apparent why it is not.